# Gradle error: Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

This is a React Native project. Worked fine on another machine but once moved to my machine it fails.

Most solutions I found, suggested adding jcenter() to the reposistories of project level gradle.build. In my case, it was already added.

Gradle sync fails with this error:

`Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
Required by:
    project :react-native-image-picker`

Android build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"

    googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55")) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

App build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sos"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
  missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative57"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
        signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && requested.name != 'multidex') {
            details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
}


// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

By the way, in app build.gralde file, the `android` in `import com.android.build.OutputFile` throws an error: can't be resolved

**Edit:**

Now that part of the build process is already passed, succesfully, but I started to get this error:
`Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-fetch-blob: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.`

[image]

Comment: try exact version of 2.2.3 it worked for me

Comment: [It seems it's not a problem you can solve](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347), some libraries were unpublished from jCenter.

Comment: Seems jCenter has fixed the issue, syncing the project again worked for me now.

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to wait until this library will release fixed version, here is how you can fix it:

Just add it to your build.gradle under subprojects section in the root (not app/gradle)

```
subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-image-picker') || 
        project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

credit goes to https://github.com/akolpakov

Comment: This answer works for me!

Comment: Saved my day. :)

Answer (score 10):

This is a new issue which was addressed in the new version of react-native-image-picker
Go to your root folder and reinstall react-native-image-picker:

```
npm install --save react-native-image-picker
```

Then go to your root folder and ensure that your react-native-image-picker is on version "^0.27.2"

Comment: Thanks! This solved that particular issue, I am having a new one now but at least that part of the build is passed! Now I am getting ```Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-fetch-blob: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.```

Answer (score 4):

The react-native-vector-icons package also encounters the same problem.

Is that caused by these two broken repositories?

```
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
```

They both response "The requested path was not found."

**Edit**

Based on the log information:

```
project :react-native-vector-icons 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: 
Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+ as 
no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
```

search the '2.3.+' and replace it with explicit version # (e.g. 2.3.0)
The problem will be solved.

I have read the suggestion from Android about avoiding the use of + in version code, that suggestion might be enforced now.

Comment: you mean to change the dependencies in the react-native-vector-icons package right? that seems like a quickfix that can backfire soon :P

Comment: Upgrading react-native-vector-icons to 6.0.2 seems to do the trick and you don't need to mess with node_modules :)

Answer (score 4):

On the day this question was made - 2018-12-10 - there was an issue lasting for over a day because JCenter received a request from Google to remove several binaries from their repository:

> Google asked us to stop providing their binaries. Please use the official Google repository for them.
>   https://twitter.com/bintray/status/1072275597315923971

If you need an immediate workaround, the best course of action would be to add any dependencies you need directly with their Maven URL. E.g.:

`repositories {
  (...)
  maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
}`

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment3

The thread above is a good place to follow the resolution of the issue as it's still ongoing as I write this.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like some repos were removed by mistake, and according to a Google representative it's something they are currently working on restoring:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30

> Hello again everyone,
>
> We now know what happened, and are working on rolling it back in a
>   sensible way.  Here's a basic outline of the problem:
>
> 1. There were some bogus/malformed com.google.* and com.android.* artifacts on jCenter
> 2. Most of these artifacts were properly hosted on maven.google.com (aka google())
> 3. If your build system found the jCenter version before it found the Google Maven version, your build would break
> 4. Google noticed this and asked jFrog to remove basically everything under com.google.* and com.android.* because we assumed it
>      was all on Google Maven as well
> 5. We were wrong :-(
> 6. Some artifacts deleted from jCenter are causing errors in your builds
>
> We are working on doing a few things:
>
> - Some libraries that were deleted are being pushed to Google Maven.
>     This includes the com.google.gms:google-services plugin, the firebase
>     performance plugin, and Exoplayer.  Try adding google() to your
>     buildscript and app repositories blocks to see if that helps.  We
>     expect this to help many people, but not everyone.   * We are working
>     to make a list of which libraries were improperly deleted.  Some of
>     the things deleted in step #4 above were done for good reason, so we
>     don't want to restore those as well.
>
> As I said before, we hate that we broke your builds and we appreciate
>   your patience while we fix it!
>
> - Sam

They also suggest the following workarounds in the meantime:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment36

> #### STATUS
>
> - The Google Services library (com.google.gms:google-services) library has been restored, see update #31.
> - Requests have been submitted to jCenter to re-publish all repositories hosted on bintray.com/google. The jCenter admins at JFrog
>     are working to get them back online for us, at this point all we can
>     do is wait. We expect them to come online soon. Some libraries are
>     already back.
> - Some Android/Firebase libraries that were dual-homed on both jcenter.bintray.com and maven.google.com are missing older versions
>     (previously hosted on jCenter). We're still working at getting these
>     back online in either jcenter.bintray.com or maven.google.com, as
>     appropriate -- we're working carefully here to avoid re-creating the
>     initial conflicts that caused problems. Work is ongoing. Newer
>     versions of these libraries are unaffected, as they're available on
>     maven.google.com.
>
> #### WORKAROUNDS
>
> 1. For the Google Services library, no workaround is necessary. This library is already restored. Other libraries in /google are in the
>      progress of being restored as well.
> 2. For projects served from bintray.com/android or bintray.com/firebase that are not resolving, consider upgrading to a
>      newer version that is already hosted on maven.google.com. (See below
>      if this is not feasible.)
> 3. For projects from bintray.com/google, or if you are unable to upgrade to a newer version of a Android or Firebase library...you will
>      need to temporarily add a block similar to the following to your
>      build.gradle:
>
>    repositories {
>         maven {
>             url  "https://google.bintray.com/$(REPOSITORY)" 
>         }    }
>
>    Replace $(REPOSITORY) with the project name from
>      https://bintray.com/google.
>
>    For bintray.com/firebase, use
>      "https://firebase.bintray.com/$(REPOSITORY)". For bintray.com/android,
>      use "https://dl.bintray.com/android/$(REPOSITORY)".
>
>    Again, this workaround is only temporary until we can get all
>      versions either re-listed in jCenter or mirrored into
>      maven.google.com.
>
> #### INVESTIGATION
>
> The request submitted to de-list projects from jCenter appears to have been overly broad, and was submitted by
>   another team at Google that did not have full authority to make that
>   change. The repository admins at Google were not consulted before this
>   request was executed by jCenter. We'll be looking into this more in
>   the days to come, right now our first priority is in restoring access
>   to all versions of affected libraries.
>
> Additionally, it appears that there may be a misconfiguration in
>   Google's repository that is preventing mirroring from maven.google.com
>   into jCenter, which in turn was the cause of the initial takedown
>   request. Correcting this misconfiguration may have avoided the need to
>   remove anything. Additional followup is occurring internally.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the exact version of gradle it worked for me

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

Answer (score 1):

For people coming across this error with react-native-vector-icons package:

1. Upgrade "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2" in package.json

Source: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/605#issuecomment-446081342